# Will a Qt based GUI app work on the Android OS?

Tags: qt, qt4

If I write a Qt Gui application in c++, will it work on the Android OS?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Necessitas](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/28/necessitas/)

Comment: I think it is possible, but with some conditions and some changes to port your application to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in this video: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/28/necessitas/

So, yes, it is possible. Personally I would recommend always using the native platform where possible - chances are it's going to be more stable across all the various Android devices.